# Regex To Find negative number in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to solve below issue using javascript , let me know if someone came across similar problem and any pointer will be really helpful.

I am working on Currency format where different country can different representation for negative currency format.

Requirement :
If a number start /end with **-** consider such value as negative.
Similarly if a number start / end  with **()** consider such value as negative.

```
-123.55 = > Negative True 
123.55 = > Negative False 
(123.55) => Negative True
```

[My code](https://jsfiddle.net/nvmzxcbj/2/):

```js
console.log('1234,56' + ' vs ' + formatNumber('1234,56', '', ','));
console.log('1234.56' + ' vs ' + formatNumber('1234.56', '', '.'));
console.log('-1,234.567' + ' VS ' + formatNumber('-1,234.567', ',', '.'));
console.log('1,234.567-' + ' VS ' + formatNumber('1,234.567-', ',', '.'));
console.log("1'234,567-" + " VS " + formatNumber("1'234,567-", "'", ','));
console.log("1'234.567-" + " VS " + formatNumber("1'234.567-", "'", '.'));
console.log("1.234,567-" + " VS " + formatNumber("1.234,567-", ".", ','));

function formatNumber(sourceString, groupseperator, decimalSeperator) {
  let negativeNumber = false;

  var negRegexp = new RegExp("[-|)]$", "g");
  var match = negRegexp.exec(sourceString);
  if (match && match.length > 0) {
    console.log(match[0]);
    negativeNumber = true;
  }

  //Step1 :Replace braces space from the string
  sourceString = sourceString.replace(/[`\s-()'\]\\\/]/gi, '');
  //Step2 :Replace All Group Seperator with blank
  sourceString = sourceString.replace(new RegExp(`[${groupseperator}]`, 'g'), '');

  //Step 3: Replace decimal seperator with .dot
  //Decimal Seperator will only replace from the last occurance
  sourceString = sourceString.replace(new RegExp(`${decimalSeperator}([^${decimalSeperator}]*)$`), '.$1');
  if (negativeNumber) {
    sourceString = '-' + sourceString;
  }
  //console.log(sourceString);
  //console.log(Number(sourceString));
  return Number(sourceString);
}
```

If you refer code  below scenario is failing .

> console.log('-1,234.567' + ' VS '+
> formatNumber('-1,234.567',',','.'));

It is returning it as positive number

Comment: What is the problem with the code?

Comment: Why does `negRegexp` match `|`? You don't need to use `|` between alternatives inside `[]`, so it's treated as a literal character.

Comment: Please put the code back in the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put the [mre] back in the question, rather than just linked off-site. Also please explain what it's meant to be showing us, and what result you want from the input you haven't described (`"1,245.51-"`).

Comment: `negRegexp` only matches `-` at the end, because of `$`. It should use `^-` to match it at the beginning.

Comment: Actually, since the code used to be there, I've put it back (no licensing issue) and added the bit you added at the end of the question. But again, please explain what you want to do with `"1,234,567-"` (and `"1'234,567-"`). Are those negative numbers? If so, you should mention them in your initial list.

Comment: Yes if a value start with or end with - I have consider it as negative.  For Example 1'234,567- will be treated as -1234.567 and -1'234,567 will be treated as -1234.567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`negRegexp` is wrong. It matches `-` at the end, but not the beginning.

Use separate alternatives in the regexp for each criteria.

```js
var negRegexp = /^-|-$|^\(.*\)$/;
console.log(negRegexp.test('-123.55')); // Negative True 
console.log(negRegexp.test('123.55')); // Negative False 
console.log(negRegexp.test('(123.55)')); // Negative True
console.log(negRegexp.test("1'234,567-")); // Negative True
```

The first alternative matches `-` at the beginning, the second matches `-` at the end, and the third matches `(` at the beginning and `)` at the end.

There's no need for the `g` flag since you're only matching one number.

Comment: If a value start with ends with  -(Hyphen) I have consider is as negative. Similarly if a value start with ( and ends with ) I have consider it as negative.

Comment: I know that. But your regular expression doesn't match that criteria. It matches `-`, `|`, or `)` at the end, but `-` has to be at the beginning.

Comment: If I can find the correct regex to find negative number issue will be resolved, it may not be the best way.  var negRegexp = new RegExp("^-|^\(.*\)$", "g");
var match = negRegexp.exec(sourceString);
if(match && match.length > 0){
//console.log(match[0]);
 negativeNumber = true;
}

Comment: Why doesn't the regexp in my answer work?

Comment: BTW, there's no need to use `new RegExp` for a static regexp, it should only be used when you're creating the regexp dynamically.

Comment: For positive number also it is considering as negative https://jsfiddle.net/aLtyh2s5/

Comment: You need to double the backslashes inside a string. You wouldn't have that problem if you used a regexp literal instead of `new RegExp`. See https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/mye0n4v8/

Comment: This scenario is not working console.log(negRegexp.test("1'234,567-"));

Comment: I added it to my snippet and it works correctly. It says it's not negative.

Comment: Number is ending with - (Hyphen) it should be consider as negative , and it should have return true

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see "start/end" in the question.